# Weird character encoding problems causing js functions to fail or add unwanted characters

Tags: php, javascript, encoding, character-encoding

A PHP function I am writing pulls a small bit of HTML data from another webpage using file_get_contents(), then parses out a piece of text and tries to store it in a database.  The problem is, the data it gets must be encoded with a different charset or something (I'm not positive how to check this) because it often adds ï»¿ (at seemingly random places in the string, not always at beginning or end) and every once in a while adds a new line where I don't want one.  The ï»¿ is annoying but when the newline is added it causes the javascript function to fail.  The javascript function is printed from a php script as follows:

```
print <<<END
    setUpSend("${a}", "${b}", "${c}", "${d}");
END;
```

And when the newline is entered, the function no longer works (I suppose because of the newline), and viewing the source shows something like this:

```
print <<<END
        setUpSend("a information", "b information
", "c information", "d information");
END;
```

I did some research and found that this ï»¿ is the UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) and it is suggested to parse the information as xml not as a string - I found that there are some php libraries to do this (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) but was thinking there might be an easier way, like a simple php function that will convert it automatically, or strip unwanted characters.

Also, sometimes the information can contain quotes, but since that would mess up the js function as well, I tried to use PHP's addslashes function and it just doesn't add any slashes, not working at all.  If I manually write the same exact string in php however, and use addslashes on that, it adds the slashes normally, so it makes me think that somehow php can't understand the encoding of this text I am getting.  Something weird is going on but I'm lost on how to fix it.

I'd be more than open to any suggestions as I've looked up a lot of stuff but can't figure out a good way to solve this.

Comment: Hi, did you apply utf8_decode to the text you extract?

Comment: @Anthony: Added some more [to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8724717/367456) as I was seeing you have a problem to obtain the original Content-Type and it's charset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ï»¿` might be an [UTF-8 encoded BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8). You can normally safely remove it if you know the source encoding is UTF-8.

That's a simple string operation:

```
$withOutUTF8BOM = remove_UTF8BOM($withOrWithOutUTF8BOM);


/**
 * Remove UTF8BOM from the beginning of a string (if it exists)
 *
 * @return string
 */
function remove_UTF8BOM($str)
{
    $UTF8BOM = "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
    (0 === strpos($str, $UTF8BOM)) && $str = (string) substr($str, 3);
    return $str;
}
```

However, it looks like that you should make your code input encoding aware. HTML data can be in different encodings, so it's probably worth to normalize the HTML encoding upfront (e.g. convert all non UTF-8 charsets to UTF-8) and then make your own functions properly deal with UTF-8 encoded data.

> A PHP function I am writing pulls a small bit of HTML data from another webpage using `file_get_contents()`, then parses out a piece of text and tries to store it in a database. The problem is, the data it gets must be encoded with a different charset or something *(I'm not positive how to check this)*

You can obtain the response headers after you retrieved the data with `file_get_contents`. Those are stored in `$http_response_header`. The following example demonstrates this
(see [*HEAD first with PHP Streams*](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/) for the `parse_http_response_header` function):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';

$body = file_get_contents($url);

$responses = parse_http_response_header($http_response_header);

$contentType = $responses[0]['fields']['CONTENT-TYPE']; // CONTENT-TYPE

echo "Content-Type: $contentType\n";  # Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

You only need to check if that header line exists and if a charset has been specified. See the [`Content-Type`<sup>*­RFC 2616*</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17) header specification how it is written:

```
list($typeAndSubType, $parameter) = explode(';' $contentType, 2) + array(NULL,NULL);
```

If there is [no media-type given (type and sub-type)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-7.2.1), you can (but must not) try to guess it. As you're dealing with HTML, this is normally `text/html`.

```
   Content-Type   = "Content-Type" ":" media-type

   media-type     = type "/" subtype *( ";" parameter )
   type           = token
   subtype        = token
```

If no charset parameter is given, take the default charset for that type (`text`). In HTTP this is `ISO‑8859` ([ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.7.1)).

To properly parse the parameter(s), please see [*Section 3.6*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6):

```
   parameter               = attribute "=" value
   attribute               = token
   value                   = token | quoted-string
```

To properly parse the parameter string I leave as an exercise.

Comment: Regarding BOM inside UTF8 streams, the UTF8 RFC has a good introduction to that: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-6

Comment: hakre thank you for the awesome and detailed answer - you helped me find out a lot more about the problem.  I looked at the html source of the page I am trying to retrieve from and couldn't find any content-type or charset meta tags.  But, I set all my pages, like you suggested, to UTF-8 and did the same with the mysql database (set it to UTF8-general). (continued on next comment)

Comment: I've realized now that the BOM doesn't appear in the string or the html of my pages, but only appears in the db, and sometimes in different spots, which is causing problems because it thinks the same entry is different every once in a while (because the string is different.)  Also, the addslashes() still doesn't work only on that text, but htmlspecialchars() does and that seems to serve the same purpose for me.  Almost there now but...any idea on how to get the bom out of the mysql db so the same entries don't duplicate?

Comment: `$noBOMNoWhere = str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF", '', $withBOManyWhere);` - should be safe to replace it everywhere normally, the replace function in the answer is just more conservative only looking at the beginning.

Comment: Nice!  That worked great, just removes it wherever it is in the string - much appreciate all your help that was driving me crazy.  Thank god for the geniuses on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Just programming Anthony ;) As written in the beginning of the answer - a simple string operation ;)

Comment: Sure everything is simple when looked at in small pieces, but knowing what knowledge to use when and how to put the small pieces together correctly is the mark of intelligence.  Anyways, regardless of difficulty level, my thanks go out for taking the time to write a detailed and expansive answer.

Comment: You're totally right, and I must apologize because next to what you write, I'm also being wrong here running into the [Blind faith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_faith_(computer_science)) trap, my original `remove_UTF8BOM` just did *not* do what I wanted it to do! I've fixed the routine, this might have been the problem already. So even I can fail with *simple* string operations ;) - So the other lesson is: We make errors, better check twice.